# Time adverbial ambiguity

Tags: adverbs

> I have booked a flight in September.

In the above sentence, does it mean the flight is in September or the action of booking is in September?

> In May, I have booked a flight back to home in September.

This sentence should be more clear than the previous one. But I feel like it is not a very good expression, is it? How do I reword this sentence so it gets better?

Comment: See [attachment ambiguity](https://www.google.com/search?q=attachment+ambiguity). As long as you use prepositional phrases at the end of the clause, there will be ambiguities. These will be unavoidable in writing, but usually not a problem in speech, where intonation and rhythm can help.

Comment: This is where our brains come in. Unless you mean the September of 10 months ago, we know you bought a ticket to fly in the September coming up. We would not think you meant that you beamed yourself forward to September to buy a ticket. Okay, *for September* would be clearer, but not a must.

Comment: What the others above said and I think you're also missing that the time is easily inferred correctly here. The second sentence does not occur in nature, because you'd say "In May, I booked a flight home for September."

Answer (score 1):

One simple (and the shortest) way of rephrasing the sentence so that it unambiguously provides the meaning you want is the following:

> I have booked a September flight.

This turns *September* into an attributive noun, leaving no room for misinterpretation.

Comment: 0r say “a flight for September.” Lots of was to say it unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

I booked a flight for Sept.(-ember) (all the way) back in (the month of) May.
I booked a flight back in May for (the month of) September.
I booked a flight for May, back (earlier) in September

Answer (score 0):

"I have booked a flight in September."

The verb is in the perfect tense, and so indicates a present state of affairs brought about by a past action.  This makes it clear that the booking happened in the past, and the flight is *next* September. There is no ambiguity.

"In May, I have booked a flight back to home in September."

This sentence does not make sense. If you mean that you made the booking in May, then you're talking about a past action, so you'd use the imperfect (past) tense.